# Does it make sense to run numpy and matplotlib code with threads?

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I wrote a Python program for each of my lab experiments to do data analysis (`numpy`, `scipy`) and plotting (`matplotlib`). Currently, I use the `matplotlib.pyplot` state machine interface which is probably not good for multiple threads. So I will look into the OO interface for that.

However, due to the global interpreter lock in Python, does it even make anything faster if I put the independent parts of my data analysis in a thread?

Comment: Most numerical calculations inside numpy release the GIL while number crunching. So if your data analysis is made up of a few numpy function calls that then run for a long time, then yes, you could use multithreading both to keep other stuff alive while that computing is going on, or even to split the calculations among several threads.

Comment: It is a non-interactive program, so “keeping stuff alive“ is not a concern. I guess I will try it out and make a speed test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried out the `multiprocessing` instead of `threading`. It turns out that I just had to replace my “final results dict `T`“ with a `multiprocessing.Manager().dict()` and got it working even with the `pyplot` state machine.

Before:

```
real    0m10.906s
user    0m10.411s
sys     0m0.312s
```

With `multiprocessing`:

```
real    0m8.979s
user    0m12.707s
sys     0m0.546s
```

So it does not look like a huge improvement, but that is just because one of the parts takes so much time, that not a lot is running in parallel. I guess `multiprocessing` is the answer.